# Create a folder in google storage bucket with Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When trying to create a folder structure inside the bucket (test-bucket123\test), I am getting error. Please refer the sample code and the error message below.

```
resources:
- name: mybucketname
  type: storage.v1.bucket
  properties:
    project: projectID
    location: {{properties['region']}}
    storageClass: {{properties['storageClass']}}
    versionning:
      enabled: false

- type: storage.v1.object
  name: test
  properties:
    project: projectID
    name: test
    bucket: mybucketname
```

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1600770967871-5afe488e8201e-2cbd6491-ae9d363b]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/my-deployment/resources/test
  message: '{"ResourceType":"storage.v1.object","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Uploads
    must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/mybucketname/o?name=test","reason":"wrongUrlForUpload"}],"message":"Uploads
    must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/mybucketname/o?name=test","statusMessage":"Bad
    Request","requestPath":"https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/mybucketname/o","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

I tried to set the urlpath property but did not work.

Could anyone guide me this.

Answer (score 0):

The folder doesn't exist in Google Storage!! It's a bucket, all the object are in the bucket, no folder. You can name your object with a path prefix `this/is/a/folder.json`. But it's only for a human representation and readability.

You can have a try. Create a file with a path in Storage, you will see directories in the console. Delete the file (only the file) and all the directory disappear!